# Create SAML Assertion and Sign the response

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have a Java web application. I want to implement SAML Single-Sign-On login for my application. I have got this [GitHub onelogin program](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml) to send request and get response. But it was not working properly. I created one account there. But I don't have an enterprise account. When I run the application, it is going to [onelogin login](https://app.onelogin.com/login) page. I tried to login, but it is not returning anyuthing in the response, showing I don't have permission. If I provide wrong credentials also, it is not giving any SAML response.

So I decided to create an assertion and sign it.

1. Do I need to send a SAML request to any identity provider first?
2. How to create a sample SAML assertion instead of going to IdP([Like this is fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384851/looking-for-feedback-on-a-first-saml-implementation))
3. Once I get the SAML response, how do I sign it in my application and proceed?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
  ID="123" InResponseTo="abc" IssueInstant="2014-11-21T17:13:42.872Z" 
  Version="2.0">
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0">
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">
                user@example.com
            </saml:NameID>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2014-11-21T17:13:42.899Z">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
                    urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
                </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use [Java Saml from Onelogin](https://github.com/onelogin/java-saml) to sign the response using their utility class (com.onelogin.saml2.util.Util):

```
// loads xml string into Document
Document document = Util.loadXML(saml);

// loads certificate and private key from string
X509Certificate cert = Util.loadCert(pubKeyBytes);
PrivateKey privateKey = Util.loadPrivateKey(privKeyBytes);

// signs the response
String signedResponse = Util.addSign(document, privateKey, cert, null);
```

You can also use another `.addSign` method that takes `Node` as first parameter to sign the assertion of the SAML response.

Their Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.onelogin</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-saml</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Wow! Great answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you need to do is to read up on the SAML protocol. I have two blogs I can recommend.

- [Intro to SAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2010/11/short-introduction-to-saml.html)
- [Intro to the Web Profile](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/05/saml-web-profile.html)

Next you can choose to build the SAML integration in your app or you can use a third party application to do the integration. Typical third party applications are [Shibboleth](http://www.internet2.edu/products-services/trust-identity-middleware/shibboleth/) and [OpenAM](http://forgerock.com/products/open-identity-stack/openam/).

If you decide to build it in to your application, you can for example use OpenSAML. OpenSAML is a library that helps to work with SAML messages. [I have several blogs on the subject](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/categories/opensaml/) and [one book that is good to start with](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html)

About your questions.

1. You don't need to send a request. The IDP can start the process without a request.
2. Well you can create one just by editing the one that you found. You can also use OpenSAML to create the assertion
3. You do not sign the response in your application, the IDP signs the response. The signature verification depends on the software. [Here is how you do it in OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/11/verifying-signatures-with-opensaml.html)

Comment: OK. So I can hard code the XML String as in other example as SAML assertion. That I don't need to sign. Then how can I validate it? I haven't stored any certificate in keystore.

Comment: I dont what the XML string is. you validate using a certifcate. This you can get from a file or from the SAML metadata

Comment: Please see the **Update 1**. The assertion I copied from other SO question. How to validate? Do I need to install a certificate before validating?

Comment: Well the Assertion you posted is not signed so you do nt need to validate. You will need the certificate. How it is used of if you need to install it depends on the software you use.

Comment: Sorry  don't get it. I am not using any software.

Comment: You need some code or software to do validation. if you start using OpenSAML you cna use the link I provided in my answere

Comment: Ok. But first I need to install Certificate right? I have a sample certificate I downloaded with extension **.cer** . Is there any link or sample code on how tp store that in keystore and update public key so that I can validate it against the SAML assertion and then get attributes like user-id and email?