# Signing Both Message and Assertion with Java Saml from Onelogin

Tags: saml-2.0, onelogin

I am trying to follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46000524/13925339

I can sign the SAML Response message:

```
        String saml = "...";
        String pubKeyBytes = "...";
        String privKeyBytes = "...";

        Document documentResponse = Util.loadXML(saml); //loads string to document

        X509Certificate cert = null;
        cert = Util.loadCert(pubKeyBytes);
        PrivateKey privateKey = Util.loadPrivateKey(privKeyBytes);

        //sign saml assertion:
        String stringSignedResponse = Util.addSign(documentResponse, privateKey, cert, null);
```

I can pull out the SAML Assertion and sign that:

```
        NodeList nodelist = documentResponse.getElementsByTagName("saml2:Assertion");
        Node nodeSamlAssertion = nodelist.item(0);

        String stringSignedSamlAssertion = Util.addSign(nodeSamlAssertion, privateKey, cert, null);
```

BUT how do I combine the two (as is possible with OneLogin's https://www.samltool.com/sign_response.php online tool in 'Sign Message and Assertion' mode)?

Comment: Why do you want to sign both? In what order are you signing things?

Comment: ..because my Service Provider appears to need both signed otherwise I get an signature verification error.

Comment: signing both shouldn't be necessary, just so you know. The only reason for doing so is if the assertion or one of the elements is encrypted.

Comment: yes, looks like I was mistaken earlier when I stated my Service Provider needed both signing, as I have got it working with just the message OR just the assertion signed. When it was failing previously there must have been something else that I had got wrong on the signature.
This has been a useful learning exercise nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Worked out how to do this by

1. Turning the String returned from Util.addSign(nodeSamlAssertion,..) back into a Node
2. Importing that Node back into the SAML response Document object.
3. Using the Element.replaceChild method to switch the unsigned SAML Assertion node with the signed SAML Assertion node

   Element nodeSignedSamlAssertion =  DocumentBuilderFactory
   .newInstance()
   .newDocumentBuilder()
   .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(stringSignedSamlAssertion.getBytes()))
   .getDocumentElement();

   ```
        Node copiedNode = documentResponse.importNode(nodeSignedSamlAssertion, true);
        documentResponse.getDocumentElement().replaceChild(copiedNode, documentResponse.getElementsByTagName("saml2:Assertion").item(0));
   ```